# Slim Post method not working with AngularJs Http Request

Tags: angularjs, slim, angularjs-controller, angularjs-http

This is my ***AngularJS*** controller :

```
app.controller('emailConfirmCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.check_credentials = function () {

    var request = $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'api/slim.php/website/email_verification',
      data: {
        email: 'email@abc.com'        
      },
      headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' }
    });

    /* Check whether the HTTP Request is successful or not. */
    request.success(function (data) {
    console.log('email sent successfully');
    console.log(data); 
    });
  }
});
```

And in my ***Slim API*** I am trying to access data like this:

```
$app->post("/website/email_verification", function () use ($app, $db) {
  $request = $app->request();
  $body =  json_decode($request->getBody());

// $email_id = $body['email']; 
 echo $body;   
});
```

But I am getting Error 404, but if I change post method to get then there is no 404 error(i.e url given in AngularJS controller is fine).

How can I access email_id in my SLIM API with post method.

Answer (score 1):

```
$app->post(
'/login',
function () use ($app) {

    $app->response()->header("Content-Type", "application/json");
    $post = json_decode($app->request()->getBody());
    $postArray = get_object_vars($post);

    $login = $postArray['login'];
    $pass = $postArray['pass'];
```

Answer (score 0):

for json you can read raw request body

you will decode the input stream

```
$body = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

in your case you can try this

```
$app->post("/website/email_verification", function () use ($app, $db) {
 $body = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
  echo $body;   
});
```

Comment: but still I am getting this error: 'POST http://localhost/website/api/slim.php/website/email_verification 500 (Internal Server Error)' in my console, how do I resolve this first?

Comment: there is an error on the php(server) side you need to fix it

Comment: Can you suggest some solutions for this server side error?